# Is there any way to customise serialization keys for classes conditionally?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter and I need to implement custom serialization that reads the json object.

My class is :

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Activity {
  @JsonKey(name: 'ActivityId')
  int activityId = 0;

  @JsonKey(name: 'ActivityType')
  int type = 0;

  @JsonKey(name: 'Title')
  String name;

  Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SFActivityAnswerQuestionAnswerPostFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      _$SFActivityAnswerQuestionAnswerPostToJson(this);
```

The problem is the keys in the API response for `Title` can change depend on the type of request and it can be `Name`.

My question is is there any way to add support to check the request and change `@JsonKey(name: 'Title')` to `@JsonKey(name: 'Name')` ?